# Getting the Only Live

Tags: mysql

I need to track salesmen and their steps.  I have two tables   Prospects and Activity.

Here is the SQL:
Sql Fiddle Here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/413e1c

```
CREATE  TABLE `Prospects` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Prospects` (`Name`) VALUES ('Tom');
INSERT INTO `Prospects` (`Name`) VALUES ('Dick');
INSERT INTO `Prospects` (`Name`) VALUES ('Harry');
INSERT INTO `Prospects` (`Name`) VALUES ('Oscar');


CREATE  TABLE `Activity` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Prospect_ID` INT NULL ,
  `Active` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Step` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `Activity` (`Prospect_ID`, `Active`, `Step`) VALUES ('1', 'Yes', 'Call');
INSERT INTO `Activity` (`Prospect_ID`, `Active`, `Step`) VALUES ('1', 'No', 'Mail');
INSERT INTO `Activity` (`Prospect_ID`, `Active`, `Step`) VALUES ('2', 'No', 'Call');
INSERT INTO `Activity` (`Prospect_ID`, `Active`, `Step`) VALUES ('3', 'Yes', 'Mail');
```

What I am looking for is the Open Activity for each prospect.   If Active = No then It should be excluded.

```
ID    Prospect    Status
1     Tom         Call
2     Dick        -None-
3     Harry       Mail
4     Oscar       -None-
```

Im stuck on two points

1.No Records to data.
2.Searching in my related file.

よろしくお願い！

Comment: I don't understand your "two points". Just to clarify, you want a query that returns the sample data you posted? What have you tried so far relating to `SELECT` statements?

Comment: Wow beaten down twice for using Kanji?

Comment: I doubt it's for using Kanji. Probably more for lack of clarity or not responding to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the result using a LEFT JOIN and place the filter for `Active = 'yes'` on the JOIN instead of in a WHERE clause. Then you can use a COALESCE to replace the `null` values:

```
select p.id, p.name, 
  coalesce(a.step, '-None-') Status
from prospects p
left join activity a
  on p.id = a.prospect_id
  and a.active = 'Yes';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02e81/5)

Comment: I suggest changing the JOIN to `INNER JOIN` to exclude records where `active='no'`. Alternatively, use a `WHERE a.active!='No'` instead of putting it in the join. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe0277/6

Comment: @showdev If you use an inner join then it will only return the rows that exist in both tables, so Oscar will not appear in the final result.  The above will give the desired result the OP requested, it will list all prospects.

Comment: But the OP wanted to only list prospects where `active!='no'`. "If Active = No then It should be excluded." Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @showdev I am still filtering that data out, but I am showing all of the prospects. The OP will need to clarify. I am basing my answer on the desire to filter out active = no and they show all prospects.

Comment: Ah okay. Maybe I misunderstood the desired functionality.